# How to make the minipages continue after each other in one page?

Tags: page-breaking, minipage

I am not sure how to make these two minipages to follow right after each other rather than showing in two different pages while still there's space in the first page:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
               \item \textbf{IoT Lab Assistant}, \href{http://www.iotlab.wisc.edu}{Internet-of-Things} lab, supervised by Dr. R. Veeramani and T. Yen, Summer 2015.
               \indent Designed tutorials and have worked with Microsoft Band, Pebble Smart Watch, CrazyFlie nanocopter, Parrot AR Drone 2, Intel Galileo Gen1 board, Arduino Yun board, Leap Motion as well as working with IBM Bluemix and Thingsworx platforms.
               \item \textbf{Mathematics and Science Lead}, Program Assistant for \href{http://www.peopleprogram.wisc.edu/}{PEOPEL} program in \href{https://eastweb.madison.k12.wi.us/}{East High School}, Coordinator: Paul Ly Tong Pao, Spring and Fall 2014, Spring 2015.
               \item \textbf{Calculus and Analytic Geometry 1 (Math221)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Gloria Mari-Beffa and Dr. Ruifang Song, Department of Mathematics, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2013.
            \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Engineering (CS252)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Guri Sohi and Dr. Mark Hill, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Spring 2013.
            \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Architecture (ECE/CS552)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Yu Hen Hu, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{Advanced Electronic Circuits (ECE342)}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Giri Vekataramanan, ECE Department,
University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{\href{http://edgaps.org/gaps/projects/nephrotex/}{Nephrotex} Virtual Internship for Freshman Engineering Students(InterEng101)}, Student Assistant and Design Advisor, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{Persian Language}, Tutor for \href{http://aptlii.global.wisc.edu/}{APTLII} Program, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Summer 2012.
               \item \textbf{Seeing through Engineer Eyes}, 3-week intensive workshop for middle school students, Instructor, University of
Wisconsin-Madison, Madison, WI.
               \item \textbf{Embedded System Design}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. A.Ejlali, Computer Engineering Department,
Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{VLSI Design},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr.M.Modarresi, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Network Laboratory}, Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Digital Design Laboratory (using Verilog HDL and implementing on Altera and Xilinx FPGAs)},Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Fall 2010.
               \item \textbf{Automated Hardware Design using VHDL},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr.A.Jahanian. Electrical and Computer Engineering Department, Shahid Beheshti University, Fall
2009.
               \item \textbf{Network Laboratory (CCNA-based, Using Packet Tracer)}, Instructor, Electrical and Computer Engineering
Department, Shahid Beheshti University, Fall 2009.


    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.015\textwidth}




\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
    \large \textsc{Selected \\ Academic \\ Projects}\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf {Toyota Driving Automation Natural User Interface}, Under supervision of Dr. B. Mutlu, Summer 2015.
        \item \textbf {Learning Over Joins, using Factorized Machine Learning algorithms for enhancing the join algorithms}, Under supervision of Dr. Jeffrey Naughton and Arun Kumar, Spring 2015.
        \item \textbf {JPEG Image Compression, Spectral Correlation, IIR and FIR Filter Design with Application in ECG, MinMax Equalizer and Windowing using MATLAB as well as A Survey on Image Segmentation using Spectral Clustering}, as Part of ECE630 Course Under Supervision of Dr. Barry Van Veen, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Survey on Community Mining in Social Networks}, CS784 final project, Under supervision of Dr. A. Doan, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Implemented Command Line Interpreter(Shell), Memory Management Module, Kernel Threads in Linux Environment as well as Modifying xv6 Simulator to Support Multi-Thread, and Lottery Scheduling}, as Part of Operating System Course, Under Supervision of Dr. R. Arpaci-dusseau, Fall 2013.
        \item \textbf{Survey on Creating Accelerator for GPU and Converting/Annotating C Benchmark for an Existing Accelerator}, Under supervision of Dr Nam Kim (co-advised by Dr. Katherine (Compton) Morrow), Spring and Summer 2013.
        \item \textbf{DySER, use of accelerators beside OpenSparcT1, on VIRTEX 7}, Under Supervision of Dr. K.Sankaralingam, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Exploiting Heterogeneity in Amazon EC2 Cloud for Better Pricing and Better Availability using CloudMeter Simulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. M. Swift and Dr. S. LU, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Design of a fully 5 stage pipelined MIPS processor with 2-way set associative cache using Verilog \& Synthesized
with Design Compiler}, Under Supervision of Dr. D. Wood, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{Designing Lab manual for FPGA Lab using Quartus}, Project Assistant, Under Supervision of J. Krachey, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{A Survey on Near-duplicate Video Detection Methods using YouTubeAPI, GoogleAppEngine, Hadoop, and Condor}, Under Supervison of Dr. C. Re, Winter
break 2011-2012.
        \item \textbf{Programming a Robot for Automated Arabidopsis Photography in Study of Roots using Visual C++}, Under Supervision of \emph{Dr. A.H. Asadi}, Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Designing as well as Upgrading the Persepolis Research Group (at UW-Madison) Website using Joomla CMS},(A Joint work with
Mohammad Khabbazian), Summer and Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Simulation of Reliable SSD-based RAID using DiskSim Simulator},  Under Supervision of Dr.H.Asadi, Fall-
Winter 2010.
               \item \textbf{Simulation-Based Fault Injection for Analyzing Embedded Processors Behavior under EMI and PSD},
Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2010.
        \item \textbf{Importing ARM ISA into PTscalar from SimpleScalar}, Under Supervision of Dr. A.Ejlali, Summer 2010.

        \item \textbf{Reliable Core Mapping onto Network-on-Chips using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Spring-
Summer 2010.
                \item \textbf{Implementation of NOC Switches to Tolerate MBU Fault using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of
Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Evaluation of Multi-Core and Parallelizing a FDTD Simulation Tool Using MDCE Toolkit in MATLAB}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahangir, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Hardware Implementation of a Fast Improved Decimal Multiplier Using VHDL},Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, June-September 2009.
                \item \textbf{Implementation and Synthesis of MIPS-R2000 using VHDL and LeonardoSpectrum}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, Spring 2009.
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

This is how it looks:
[image]
[image]

Comment: `minipage`s can't break over pages. The second minipage here looks too long to fit to the lower part of the page where the first minipage is placed, so it must be shifted to another page. You need breakable box environment, such as `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`. And please provide compilable examples, not just fragments of code

Comment: please make your code complete I mean add `\documentclass.....\end{document}`

Comment: why are you using minipage here?

Answer (score 3):

A minipage can't be broken to spread it's content over multiple pages, that's why it's called a `minipage`. If content larger than would fit on a page is put into a minipage, the minipage content is shifted to the next page and clipped off at the page bottom. This is certainly not what is desired here.

A proposition: Use the `breakable` feature of `tcolorbox` and fake a minipage of width `0.85\textwidth`, it will break automatically then and the `itemize` list hasn't to be interrupted.

Another important question is: Is a `minipage` needed at all?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{marginnote}


\newtcolorbox{minipagefake}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0pt,width=0.85\textwidth,colback=white,#1}



\begin{document}

\begin{minipagefake}
      \begin{itemize}
               \item \textbf{IoT Lab Assistant}, \href{http://www.iotlab.wisc.edu}{Internet-of-Things} lab, supervised by Dr. R. Veeramani and T. Yen, Summer 2015.
               \indent Designed tutorials and have worked with Microsoft Band, Pebble Smart Watch, CrazyFlie nanocopter, Parrot AR Drone 2, Intel Galileo Gen1 board, Arduino Yun board, Leap Motion as well as working with IBM Bluemix and Thingsworx platforms.
               \item \textbf{Mathematics and Science Lead}, Program Assistant for \href{http://www.peopleprogram.wisc.edu/}{PEOPEL} program in \href{https://eastweb.madison.k12.wi.us/}{East High School}, Coordinator: Paul Ly Tong Pao, Spring and Fall 2014, Spring 2015.
               \item \textbf{Calculus and Analytic Geometry 1 (Math221)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Gloria Mari-Beffa and Dr. Ruifang Song, Department of Mathematics, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2013.
            \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Engineering (CS252)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Guri Sohi and Dr. Mark Hill, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Spring 2013.
            \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Architecture (ECE/CS552)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Yu Hen Hu, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{Advanced Electronic Circuits (ECE342)}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Giri Vekataramanan, ECE Department,
University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{\href{http://edgaps.org/gaps/projects/nephrotex/}{Nephrotex} Virtual Internship for Freshman Engineering Students(InterEng101)}, Student Assistant and Design Advisor, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{Persian Language}, Tutor for \href{http://aptlii.global.wisc.edu/}{APTLII} Program, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Summer 2012.
               \item \textbf{Seeing through Engineer Eyes}, 3-week intensive workshop for middle school students, Instructor, University of
Wisconsin-Madison, Madison, WI.
               \item \textbf{Embedded System Design}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. A.Ejlali, Computer Engineering Department,
Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{VLSI Design},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr.M.Modarresi, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Network Laboratory}, Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Digital Design Laboratory (using Verilog HDL and implementing on Altera and Xilinx FPGAs)},Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Fall 2010.
               \item \textbf{Automated Hardware Design using VHDL},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr.A.Jahanian. Electrical and Computer Engineering Department, Shahid Beheshti University, Fall
2009.
               \item \textbf{Network Laboratory (CCNA-based, Using Packet Tracer)}, Instructor, Electrical and Computer Engineering
Department, Shahid Beheshti University, Fall 2009.

\marginnote{\large \textsc{Selected \\ Academic \\ Projects}}

        \item \textbf {Toyota Driving Automation Natural User Interface}, Under supervision of Dr. B. Mutlu, Summer 2015.
        \item \textbf {Learning Over Joins, using Factorized Machine Learning algorithms for enhancing the join algorithms}, Under supervision of Dr. Jeffrey Naughton and Arun Kumar, Spring 2015.
        \item \textbf {JPEG Image Compression, Spectral Correlation, IIR and FIR Filter Design with Application in ECG, MinMax Equalizer and Windowing using MATLAB as well as A Survey on Image Segmentation using Spectral Clustering}, as Part of ECE630 Course Under Supervision of Dr. Barry Van Veen, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Survey on Community Mining in Social Networks}, CS784 final project, Under supervision of Dr. A. Doan, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Implemented Command Line Interpreter(Shell), Memory Management Module, Kernel Threads in Linux Environment as well as Modifying xv6 Simulator to Support Multi-Thread, and Lottery Scheduling}, as Part of Operating System Course, Under Supervision of Dr. R. Arpaci-dusseau, Fall 2013.
        \item \textbf{Survey on Creating Accelerator for GPU and Converting/Annotating C Benchmark for an Existing Accelerator}, Under supervision of Dr Nam Kim (co-advised by Dr. Katherine (Compton) Morrow), Spring and Summer 2013.
        \item \textbf{DySER, use of accelerators beside OpenSparcT1, on VIRTEX 7}, Under Supervision of Dr. K.Sankaralingam, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Exploiting Heterogeneity in Amazon EC2 Cloud for Better Pricing and Better Availability using CloudMeter Simulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. M. Swift and Dr. S. LU, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Design of a fully 5 stage pipelined MIPS processor with 2-way set associative cache using Verilog \& Synthesized
with Design Compiler}, Under Supervision of Dr. D. Wood, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{Designing Lab manual for FPGA Lab using Quartus}, Project Assistant, Under Supervision of J. Krachey, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{A Survey on Near-duplicate Video Detection Methods using YouTubeAPI, GoogleAppEngine, Hadoop, and Condor}, Under Supervison of Dr. C. Re, Winter
break 2011-2012.
        \item \textbf{Programming a Robot for Automated Arabidopsis Photography in Study of Roots using Visual C++}, Under Supervision of \emph{Dr. A.H. Asadi}, Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Designing as well as Upgrading the Persepolis Research Group (at UW-Madison) Website using Joomla CMS},(A Joint work with
Mohammad Khabbazian), Summer and Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Simulation of Reliable SSD-based RAID using DiskSim Simulator},  Under Supervision of Dr.H.Asadi, Fall-
Winter 2010.
               \item \textbf{Simulation-Based Fault Injection for Analyzing Embedded Processors Behavior under EMI and PSD},
Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2010.
        \item \textbf{Importing ARM ISA into PTscalar from SimpleScalar}, Under Supervision of Dr. A.Ejlali, Summer 2010.

        \item \textbf{Reliable Core Mapping onto Network-on-Chips using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Spring-
Summer 2010.
                \item \textbf{Implementation of NOC Switches to Tolerate MBU Fault using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of
Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Evaluation of Multi-Core and Parallelizing a FDTD Simulation Tool Using MDCE Toolkit in MATLAB}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahangir, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Hardware Implementation of a Fast Improved Decimal Multiplier Using VHDL},Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, June-September 2009.
                \item \textbf{Implementation and Synthesis of MIPS-R2000 using VHDL and LeonardoSpectrum}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, Spring 2009.
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipagefake}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the intermediate rule in the original code is missing?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I removed it on purpose

Comment: Isn't a little risky to remove elements from the original document? What if they are required?.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I didn't hold it as useful -- I will bring that rule later on.

Answer (score 2):

> [image]
>   [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1.375in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8in}
\newcommand{\LHEAD}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\large\scshape#1}}

\begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Mathematics and Science Lead}, Program Assistant for \href{http://www.peopleprogram.wisc.edu/}{PEOPEL} program in \href{https://eastweb.madison.k12.wi.us/}{East High School}, Coordinator: Paul Ly Tong Pao, Spring and Fall 2014, Spring 2015.
         \item \textbf{Calculus and Analytic Geometry 1 (Math221)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Gloria Mari-Beffa and Dr. Ruifang Song, Department of Mathematics, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2013.
         \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Engineering (CS252)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Guri Sohi and Dr. Mark Hill, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Spring 2013.
         \item \textbf{Introduction to Computer Architecture (ECE/CS552)},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Yu Hen Hu, ECE/CS
Department, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
          \item \textbf{Advanced Electronic Circuits (ECE342)}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. Giri Vekataramanan, ECE Department,
University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{\href{http://edgaps.org/gaps/projects/nephrotex/}{Nephrotex} Virtual Internship for Freshman Engineering Students (InterEng 101)}, Student Assistant and Design Advisor, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Fall 2012.
               \item \textbf{Persian Language}, Tutor for \href{http://aptlii.global.wisc.edu/}{APTLII} Program, University of Wisconsin-Madison, Summer 2012.
               \item \textbf{Seeing through Engineer Eyes}, 3-week intensive workshop for middle school students, Instructor, University of
Wisconsin-Madison, Madison, WI.
               \item \textbf{Embedded System Design}, Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. A.Ejlali, Computer Engineering Department,
Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{VLSI Design},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr.M.Modarresi, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Network Laboratory}, Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2011.
               \item \textbf{Digital Design Laboratory (using Verilog HDL and implementing on Altera and Xilinx FPGAs)},Instructor, Computer Engineering Department, Sharif
University of Technology, Fall 2010.
               \item \textbf{Automated Hardware Design using VHDL},Teaching Assistant, Instructor: Dr. A. Jahanian. Electrical and Computer Engineering Department, Shahid Beheshti University, Fall
2009.
               \item \textbf{Network Laboratory (CCNA-based, Using Packet Tracer)}, Instructor, Electrical and Computer Engineering
Department, Shahid Beheshti University, Fall 2009.
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.015\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
\item \LHEAD{Selected Academic Projects}%
        \textbf {Toyota Driving Automation Natural User Interface}, Under supervision of Dr. B. Mutlu, Summer 2015.
        \item \textbf {Learning Over Joins, using Factorized Machine Learning algorithms for enhancing the join algorithms}, Under supervision of Dr. Jeffrey Naughton and Arun Kumar, Spring 2015.
        \item \textbf {JPEG Image Compression, Spectral Correlation, IIR and FIR Filter Design with Application in ECG, MinMax Equalizer and Windowing using MATLAB as well as A Survey on Image Segmentation using Spectral Clustering}, as Part of ECE630 Course Under Supervision of Dr. Barry Van Veen, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Survey on Community Mining in Social Networks}, CS784 final project, Under supervision of Dr. A. Doan, Spring 2014.
        \item \textbf {Implemented Command Line Interpreter(Shell), Memory Management Module, Kernel Threads in Linux Environment as well as Modifying xv6 Simulator to Support Multi-Thread, and Lottery Scheduling}, as Part of Operating System Course, Under Supervision of Dr. R. Arpaci-dusseau, Fall 2013.
        \item \textbf{Survey on Creating Accelerator for GPU and Converting/Annotating C Benchmark for an Existing Accelerator}, Under supervision of Dr Nam Kim (co-advised by Dr. Katherine (Compton) Morrow), Spring and Summer 2013.
        \item \textbf{DySER, use of accelerators beside OpenSparcT1, on VIRTEX 7}, Under Supervision of Dr. K.Sankaralingam, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Exploiting Heterogeneity in Amazon EC2 Cloud for Better Pricing and Better Availability using CloudMeter Simulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. M. Swift and Dr. S. LU, Fall 2012.
        \item \textbf{Design of a fully 5 stage pipelined MIPS processor with 2-way set associative cache using Verilog \& Synthesized
with Design Compiler}, Under Supervision of Dr. D. Wood, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{Designing Lab manual for FPGA Lab using Quartus}, Project Assistant, Under Supervision of J. Krachey, Spring 2012.
        \item \textbf{A Survey on Near-duplicate Video Detection Methods using YouTubeAPI, GoogleAppEngine, Hadoop, and Condor}, Under Supervison of Dr. C. Re, Winter
break 2011-2012.
        \item \textbf{Programming a Robot for Automated Arabidopsis Photography in Study of Roots using Visual C++}, Under Supervision of \emph{Dr. A.H. Asadi}, Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Designing as well as Upgrading the Persepolis Research Group (at UW-Madison) Website using Joomla CMS},(A Joint work with
Mohammad Khabbazian), Summer and Fall 2011.
        \item \textbf{Simulation of Reliable SSD-based RAID using DiskSim Simulator},  Under Supervision of Dr.H.Asadi, Fall-
Winter 2010.
        \item \textbf{Simulation-Based Fault Injection for Analyzing Embedded Processors Behavior under EMI and PSD},
Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2010.
        \item \textbf{Importing ARM ISA into PTscalar from SimpleScalar}, Under Supervision of Dr. A.Ejlali, Summer 2010.

        \item \textbf{Reliable Core Mapping onto Network-on-Chips using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Spring-
Summer 2010.
                \item \textbf{Implementation of NOC Switches to Tolerate MBU Fault using Xmulator}, Under Supervision of
Dr. S.G.Miremadi, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Evaluation of Multi-Core and Parallelizing a FDTD Simulation Tool Using MDCE Toolkit in MATLAB}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahangir, Fall 2009.
                \item \textbf{Hardware Implementation of a Fast Improved Decimal Multiplier Using VHDL},Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, June-September 2009.
                \item \textbf{Implementation and Synthesis of MIPS-R2000 using VHDL and LeonardoSpectrum}, Under Supervision of
Dr. A.Jahanian, Spring 2009.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

No need for `minipage`s or any special frame environment. You can just use the `\marginpar` macro after setting up the required position and width of that `\marginpar`. The following three lines move the `\marginpar` to the left, give it a width of `0.8in`, and define size and shape of the font, respectively.

```
\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8in}
\newcommand{\LHEAD}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\large\scshape#1}}
```

You can adjust the lengths as you wish and the `\LHEAD{}` command can be inserted within an item without any space after it.

Of course, you will need also to set margins using `geometry` package like this:

```
\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1.375in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}
```

Comment: The original code had a rule in between the main "sections".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, I restored it now I didn't notice.