# why isn't this properly formatted using \item \LHEAD?

Tags: formatting, margins, itemize, geometry, cv

I followed the answer given by AboAmmar [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265663/46640) by I get the following shape for my resume. Not sure why the items written in LHEAD show like that?
[image]

```
    %\documentclass[9pt,A4paper]{report}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1.375in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}


\def\name{  \color{blue}\href{http://www.linkedin.com/pub/mona-jalal/40/2/3b4}{Mona Jalal} }

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    urlcolor = blue,
    pdfauthor = {\name},
    pdfkeywords = {CV, Mona Jalal, Electrical and Computer Engineering, University of Wisconsin-Madison},
    pdftitle = {\name: Curriculum Vitae},
    pdfsubject = {Curriculum Vitae},
    pdfpagemode = UseNone
}

\geometry{
    body={7in, 10in},
    left=0.5in,
    top=0.75in
}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
%\markright{\name 's CV, Last Updated: \today}
\thispagestyle{empty}
% Don't indent paragraphs.
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\renewenvironment{itemize}{
    \begin{list}{}{
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.25em}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
    }
}{
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8in}
\newcommand{\LHEAD}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\large\scshape#1}}




    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}
    %\hrule
    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}


        \begin{itemize}
        \item \LHEAD{Curricular Activities}%
            \item \href{http://research.cs.wisc.edu/wacm/officers.html}{WACM}: Activity Chair, 2013-2015; Mentoring Chair, 2015-2016. 
            \item \href{http://sacm.cs.wisc.edu/}{SACM}: Social Chair, 2014-2015. 
            \item \href{http://chialphauw.org/Chi_Alpha/Welcome.html}{Madison CHI ALPHA}: Reader in tour of Madison and member.
            \item {Society of Women Engineer} : UW-Madison SWE collegiate member,2014-2015 academic year.
            \item {ACM}: Active student membership, 2014-2015 academic year.
            \item {Systers}: Member, Starting fall 2014.
            \item {Hoofers Sailing Club}: Member, Summer 2015.

        \end{itemize}


    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}



        \begin{itemize}
            \item \LHEAD{Langauges}%
            \item \textbf{Persian}: Native
            \item \textbf{English}: Fluent
            \item \textbf{French}: Intermediate
            \item \textbf{Italian}: Familiar
            \item \textbf{Arabic}: Familiar
        \end{itemize}



    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}


        \begin{itemize}
            \item \LHEAD{Interests}%

            \item Sailing
            \item Cooking
            \item Swimming
            \item Badminton
            \item Dancing
            \item Watercolor Painting
            \item Portrait Drawing
            \item Verse Writing
            \item talentbuddy.co
        \end{itemize}
```

Comment: First remove `\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: done but why is it showing like so ? any idea?

Comment: for me it works fine with `article` class.

Comment: Can you please write the correct answer?

Comment: I will delete my answer soon as it (almost) same.

Comment: @touhami: If it's an answer... it's an answer ;-)

Comment: @MonaJalal: Now you've added code not visible to us which could be important. And it's even incomplete!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry I am new to this LaTeX thing. I am using a friend's layout and now I am stuck

Comment: @MonaJalal: You've added a `\geometry` statement after `\hypersetup` which screws up the margins. Remove those 5 lines and `touhami`'s answer will do.

Comment: by typeing `\geometry{
    body={7in, 10in},
    left=0.5in,
    top=0.75in
}` left margin is 0.5 inch not suffi for margine try with `\geometry{
    body={7in, 10in},
    left=1.5in,
    top=0.75in
}`

Comment: @touhami like this? because `\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1.375in,right=1in,left=1.5in,body={7in, 10in}]{geometry}` doesn't change it.

Comment: I update my answer it's because left margine is 0.5 in and LHEAD item are 0.8in in this margin so can't go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1.375in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8in}
\newcommand{\LHEAD}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\large\scshape#1}}


\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
%\hrule
\vspace{0.015\textwidth}


    \begin{itemize}
    \item \LHEAD{Curricular Activities}%
        \item \href{http://research.cs.wisc.edu/wacm/officers.html}{WACM}: Activity Chair, 2013-2015; Mentoring Chair, 2015-2016. 
        \item \href{http://sacm.cs.wisc.edu/}{SACM}: Social Chair, 2014-2015. 
        \item \href{http://chialphauw.org/Chi_Alpha/Welcome.html}{Madison CHI ALPHA}: Reader in tour of Madison and member.
        \item {Society of Women Engineer} : UW-Madison SWE collegiate member,2014-2015 academic year.
        \item {ACM}: Active student membership, 2014-2015 academic year.
        \item {Systers}: Member, Starting fall 2014.
        \item {Hoofers Sailing Club}: Member, Summer 2015.

    \end{itemize}


\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.015\textwidth}



    \begin{itemize}
        \item \LHEAD{Langauges}%
        \item \textbf{Persian}: Native
        \item \textbf{English}: Fluent
        \item \textbf{French}: Intermediate
        \item \textbf{Italian}: Familiar
        \item \textbf{Arabic}: Familiar
    \end{itemize}



\vspace{0.015\textwidth}
\hrule
\vspace{0.015\textwidth}


    \begin{itemize}
        \item \LHEAD{Interests}%

        \item Sailing
        \item Cooking
        \item Swimming
        \item Badminton
        \item Dancing
        \item Watercolor Painting
        \item Portrait Drawing
        \item Verse Writing
        \item talentbuddy.co
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
%\documentclass[9pt,A4paper]{report}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,microtype,tikz} % tikz here just for colors
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    body={7in, 10in},
    left=1.5in,
    top=0.75in
}

\def\name{  \color{blue}\href{http://www.linkedin.com/pub/mona-jalal/40/2/3b4}{Mona Jalal} }

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    urlcolor = blue,
    pdfauthor = {\name},
    pdfkeywords = {CV, Mona Jalal, Electrical and Computer Engineering, University of Wisconsin-Madison},
    pdftitle = {\name: Curriculum Vitae},
    pdfsubject = {Curriculum Vitae},
    pdfpagemode = UseNone
}


\pagestyle{myheadings}
%\markright{\name 's CV, Last Updated: \today}
\thispagestyle{empty}
% Don't indent paragraphs.
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\renewenvironment{itemize}{
    \begin{list}{}{
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.25em}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
    }
}{
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8in}
\newcommand{\LHEAD}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\large\scshape#1}}




    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}
    %\hrule
    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}


        \begin{itemize}
        \item \LHEAD{Curricular Activities}%
            \item \href{http://research.cs.wisc.edu/wacm/officers.html}{WACM}: Activity Chair, 2013-2015; Mentoring Chair, 2015-2016. 
            \item \href{http://sacm.cs.wisc.edu/}{SACM}: Social Chair, 2014-2015. 
            \item \href{http://chialphauw.org/Chi_Alpha/Welcome.html}{Madison CHI ALPHA}: Reader in tour of Madison and member.
            \item {Society of Women Engineer} : UW-Madison SWE collegiate member,2014-2015 academic year.
            \item {ACM}: Active student membership, 2014-2015 academic year.
            \item {Systers}: Member, Starting fall 2014.
            \item {Hoofers Sailing Club}: Member, Summer 2015.

        \end{itemize}


    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}



        \begin{itemize}
            \item \LHEAD{Langauges}%
            \item \textbf{Persian}: Native
            \item \textbf{English}: Fluent
            \item \textbf{French}: Intermediate
            \item \textbf{Italian}: Familiar
            \item \textbf{Arabic}: Familiar
        \end{itemize}



    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.015\textwidth}


        \begin{itemize}
            \item \LHEAD{Interests}%

            \item Sailing
            \item Cooking
            \item Swimming
            \item Badminton
            \item Dancing
            \item Watercolor Painting
            \item Portrait Drawing
            \item Verse Writing
            \item talentbuddy.co
        \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: please look at my update. what you said still doesn't work for me!

Comment: @MonaJalal: Works for me.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer so any idea why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: There's a stray `bullet` from the `\item \LHEAD ...`  Perhaps it should be replaced with `\item[] \LHEAD...`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  sorry I can't see what do you point.

Comment: @touhami: It was in the first version, now it's gone, since there no bullets any longer in the `itemize` environment. Never mind ;-)

Comment: so how can I eventually fix this?

Comment: @MonaJalal you have `\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1.375in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}` but  later you have reset  margins with `\geometry{
    body={7in, 10in},
    left=0.5in,
    top=0.75in
}` here left=0.5in too small for maginpar of 0.8in